# How to check if items in cart exists or not

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a Cart model like this

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items', null=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(source='product.image', read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(source='product.name', read_only=True)
    price = serializers.DecimalField(source='product.price', read_only=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'product', 'image', 'name', 'price', 'quantity']
```

**views.py**

```
class CartApiView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Cart.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CartSerializer



def post(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = CartSerializer(data=request.data)

if serializer.is_valid():
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=request.data['product'])
    #quantity = int(request.data['quantity'])
    while Cart.objects.filter(product=product).exists():
        quantity += 1
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

before adding product to my cart I want to check it whether this product exists or not. If exists it should update the quantity if not new cart item should be added to cart. In short, First I should check before adding. But in this model `quantity` has default value. If user does not add quantity it should 1. How can I write this method? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is simple query.

```
Cart.objects.filter(user=user, product=product).exists()
```

You use `user` and `product` which you want to check. You can even include the quantity if you like:

```
Cart.objects.filter(user=user, product=product, quantity=1).exists()
```

or:

```
Cart.objects.filter(user=user, product=product, quantity__gte=1).exists()
```

it would useful that you also include your 'methods" which you tried. Because this answer is simple and obvious. So perhaps, you forgot to mention something else.

Comment: please have a look I have added a method but it does not work in this view.

Comment: @Nerd i think that you need to change your quesiton. Because you asked "how to check if exists" but it seems that you want to update cart instead

Comment: here please have a look. I am new to Django that's why I something is not clear let me know then I will add

Comment: But now it seems that you want to check if product exists. You want to check if product exists or if product exists in cart for specific user ?

Comment: yes of course every user has own cart when they are registered. Thta's why this cart is for every specific users. How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```html
qs = Cart.objects.filter(product=product)
exists = qs.exists()
if exists:
  do sth
else:
  do sth
```